# Get Hop-count between 2 peers

Tags: networking, routes, p2p

I know I should be asking this question on Network Engineering section of Stack Exchange but it feels like it's a desert there.

I'm trying to build an application that requires the distance between 2 hosts (represented by IP).

I used many methods: one of them is to get the distance at the internet layer of the TCP/IP model; i.e: the hop count between the 2 networks or better to get the bandwidths of the path but I think this information can't be measured because it's a real time info.

I figured out that there should be a graph representing the internet graph which its nodes are the routers (or autonumus systems or sub-networks (I really don't know exactly what type of nodes it should be) and the edges of the graph should be the cables between the nodes which have the bandwidth to be the wieght of the edge.

**My Question:**

Where can I find this information; whether the full graph or parts of it or something like an API to get 2 IPs and return the shortest path between the 2 IPs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool named "Tracert"
You could have it try.
It will represent the routines of peer to peer in internet.
Hope that it make

Comment: The problem with "Tracert" is it will take a long time for each request, so I can't use it. I need much faster way.

Comment: @user3098586 there can be no faster ways (or maps) cause routes are also real-time data - one packet can be routed one way and in 5 minutes another packet will go a different way. Tracert which uses raw sockets is your only option.